# Querying a database with oop

Tags: php, database

I have connected to a database for the first time with oop and stright away come up with an issue, below is my code which i'm struggling with:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM test';
       $sqli->query($q);

       if($sqli->query($q)){
           echo "worked";               
       }

       if($sqli->error){
           echo $sqli->error;
       }
```

I have checked for errors when connecting to the db and that works fine, but when I run this query I get no output, why? I expected an error or "worked", but have got neither.

Whats happening?

Comment: What is the return value for `$sqli->query()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have put some comments in the source code to help:

```
   $q = 'SELECT * FROM test';
   //$sqli is the result of a 
   //new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
   $resource = $sqli->query($q); // this returns a resource or false

   if(!$resource) {
       echo $sqli->error;
       die; // do not process further
   }

   // process the results
   $rows = $resource->fetch_all();
   if ($rows) {  // check if there are rows 
     echo "worked";               
   }
   else {
     echo "query is ok, but there are no rows"; 
   }
```

Comment: My apologies, I have finally realised what I have done, When testing the page in the browser I was testing the connection page which I had already established there were no problems with. Guess I shouldnt try to learn to code when half asleep. SORRY FOR NOT COMMENTING IT, im trying to get in the habit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use $resource->fetch_object() which returns an object for output.  Therefore if you wanted to print specific data from the result set,  you would do something like

```
//table test.Name and test.Country
while ($rowobj = $resource->fetch_object()){
          printf ("%s (%s)\n", $rowobj->Name, $rowobj->Country);
        }
```

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method, I hope it's what you are looking for. You will need to define the DB first. Then you can connect in OOP and test the connection is true or exit();

Let me know if this works for you. You can also define the DB in an external file and just do an include(); towards the top of your script for any pages needing connection to the DB.

```
define("SERVER","IP Address");
define("USER","DB USERNAME");
define("PASSWORD","DB PASSWORD");
define("DATABASE","DB NAME");
```

`// This is for connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connection to MySQL failed: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}`